# Размещение веб-приложения на кластере

Tags: кластер, веб-сервер, хостинг

Что можно сделать, если для приложения не хватает мощностей одного физического сервера? Как можно использовать объединения серверов, не меняя код приложения, но повышая его производительность?

Comment: Не хватает каких именно мощностей - скорости БД, диска, процессора, памяти?

Comment: процессора и памяти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое самое простое это вынос БД на отдельный сервер. Изменения затронут только строку подключения к БД, вместо localhost пишем ip сервера с базой и все.